# Generic code coverage with SonarQube - Can not add the same measure twice

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've been trying to load into sonarqube a coverage report for a non-standard file type.  Unfortunately I see a sonar error when I try this.

My test file, test.soc, is :-

```
Some line
Another line
Third line
```

and my coverage file, cov.xml, is :-

```
<coverage version="1">
    <file path="./test.soc">
        <lineToCover lineNumber="1" covered="true"/>
        <lineToCover lineNumber="2" covered="true"/>
    </file>
</coverage>
```

The maven pom.xml contains :-

```
    <properties>
        <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.inclusions>*.soc</sonar.inclusions>
        <sonar.verbose>true</sonar.verbose>
        <sonar.import_unknown_files>true</sonar.import_unknown_files>
        <sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/cov.xml</sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths>
    </properties>
```

When I run this, the file appears to get loaded but I see the following error :-

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project test: 
Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@20852557[key=test.soc,path=test.soc,filename=test.soc,language=<null>]: 
org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@1618a359[metricKey=lines_to_cover,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=lines_to_cover,description=Lines to cover,type=INT,direction=1,domain=Tests,name=Lines to cover,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=2.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false] -> [Help 1]
```

The stack trace is :-

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@5baab8b6[key=test.soc,path=test.soc,filename=test.soc,language=<null>]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@5c6204e5[metricKey=lines_to_cover,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=lines_to_cover,description=Lines to cover,type=INT,direction=1,domain=Tests,name=Lines to cover,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=2.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@5baab8b6[key=test.soc,path=test.soc,filename=test.soc,language=<null>]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@5c6204e5[metricKey=lines_to_cover,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=lines_to_cover,description=Lines to cover,type=INT,direction=1,domain=Tests,name=Lines to cover,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=2.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@5baab8b6[key=test.soc,path=test.soc,filename=test.soc,language=<null>]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@5c6204e5[metricKey=lines_to_cover,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=lines_to_cover,description=Lines to cover,type=INT,direction=1,domain=Tests,name=Lines to cover,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=2.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@5baab8b6[key=test.soc,path=test.soc,filename=test.soc,language=<null>]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@5c6204e5[metricKey=lines_to_cover,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=lines_to_cover,description=Lines to cover,type=INT,direction=1,domain=Tests,name=Lines to cover,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=2.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false]
    at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.addMeasure(DefaultIndex.java:245)
    at org.sonar.batch.deprecated.DeprecatedSensorContext.saveMeasure(DeprecatedSensorContext.java:189)
    at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser.saveCoverageMeasure(ReportParser.java:303)
    at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.ReportParser.saveMeasures(ReportParser.java:296)
    at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.GenericCoverageSensor.loadReport(GenericCoverageSensor.java:126)
    at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.GenericCoverageSensor.analyseWithLogger(GenericCoverageSensor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.plugins.coverage.generic.GenericCoverageSensor.analyse(GenericCoverageSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
```

Now I did try to blindly catch and ignore this exception and this got me further ... however although the individual file coverage was uploaded to sonarqube, the project summaries remained at zero.

Can the sonarcube generic code coverage plugin be used in this way for unknown file types ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, trying to attach code coverage to an unknown type file is currently not supported.

Unfortunately it leads to a bug, so I've created a ticket to fix this: [SONARCOVRG-13](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCOVRG-13)